# Dropdown menu closes when there is javascript interaction inside a webview page on Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview that shows an html page with a dropdown menu (html select tag).

I also have a setInterval that writes on the page something every second.

If I clic on the dropdown the menu opens, but as soon as the setInterval calls the method to write something on the page, the dropdown menu closes without any interaction from the user.

This is a sample setup to reproduce the problem, solving this would solve my real issue. Also it seems that the menu closes as soon as there is javscript interaction with the page, even if nothing is drawn but a callback is called from ja or app through javascript interface.

This works fine on android 4.4 with chromium but it shows this problem on android < 4.4

Is this a bug on the webview or is there a workaround?

Comment: We are having the same problem in our app. It seems to be a bug in the webview on many phones but we still have not found a workaround.